# Why it tell "invalid identifier (ORA-00904)"? when I call function in CONSTRAINT CHECK

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle11gr2

This is some kind of study database in sql file. I use oracle 11g and process it in sqlplus.

I wrote two function for check the course number and the department number, so its depend on the major and the minor department of each student.

For example, I am student of CS department (major) and BIO department (minor), so I can not enroll the course which is about math department.

When I call it in CHECK but I don't know why it told that.

This is output when I create all table, (from sqlplus)

```
     ....
     ....
     ....
table created.
ALTER TABLE sections ADD CONSTRAINT CK_course_depart CHECK (FindMYDeparture(stuid,find_dno_from_cno(cno)) = 'true');
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-0094: "FIND_DNO_FROM_CNO":invalid identifier
```

---

This is in .sql file

```
DROP TABLE department CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE department (
    dnumber      number(4) not null,
    dname        varchar(25) not null,
    primary key (dnumber)
);

DROP TABLE courses CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE courses (
    cno      number(4) not null,
    cname    varchar(15) not null,
    credit    number(1) not null,
    dnumber   number(4) not null,
    primary key (cno),
    foreign key (dnumber) references department(dnumber),
    CONSTRAINT credits CHECK (credit > 0 AND credit <= 5)
);

DROP TABLE student CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE student (
    stuid    char(9) not null,
    fname    varchar(15) not null,
    lname    varchar(15) not null,
    dMjno      number(4) not null,
    dMnno      number(4),
    primary key (stuid),
    CONSTRAINT depart_M_n CHECK (dMjno <> dMnno),
    CONSTRAINT dMinor_check CHECK (dMnno = 1 OR dMnno = 2 OR dMnno = 3) 
);

DROP TABLE sections CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE sections (
    sno      number(4)  not null,
    cno      number(4)  not null,
    stuid    char(9) not null,
    semester    varchar(6)  not null,
    year    varchar(4)  not null,
    instructor  varchar(15)  not null,
    CONSTRAINT  combine_pk primary key (sno,stuid),
    foreign key (cno) references courses(cno),
    foreign key (stuid) references student(stuid),
    CONSTRAINT cant_enroll CHECK (semester <> 'Spring' AND year <> 2007)
);

DROP TABLE grading CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE grading (
    sno      number(4) not null,
    stuid    char(9) not null,
    grade  numeric(1,2),
    foreign key (sno,stuid) references sections(sno,stuid),
    foreign key (stuid) references student(stuid),
    CONSTRAINT grading_check CHECK (grade >= 0 AND grade <= 4)

);

DROP FUNCTION FindMYDeparture;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FindMYDeparture(stuid_in IN char,depart_course IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER AS
departMa_no  NUMBER;
departMi_no  NUMBER;
report varchar(10);
CURSOR cdno is
SELECT dMjno,dMnno FROM student WHERE stuid = stuid_in;

BEGIN
OPEN cdno;
LOOP
FETCH cdno INTO departMa_no,departMi_no;
IF (departMa_no = depart_course OR departMi_no = depart_course)
THEN
report := 'true';
EXIT;
ELSE 
report := 'flase';
END IF;
EXIT WHEN cdno%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cdno;
RETURN report;
END;
/

DROP FUNCTION find_dno_from_cno;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_dno_from_cno(cno_in IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER AS
depart_no NUMBER;
CURSOR cdno is
SELECT dnumber FROM courses WHERE cno = cno_in;
BEGIN
OPEN cdno;
FETCH cdno INTO depart_no;
CLOSE cdno;
RETURN depart_no;
END;
/

ALTER TABLE sections ADD CONSTRAINT CK_course_depart CHECK (FindMYDeparture(stuid,find_dno_from_cno(cno)) = 'true');
```

Comment: Looks similar: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778948/check-constraint-calling-a-function-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: a trigger might do your task

Answer (score 2):

Not going to happen. You are not allowed to use your pl/sql functions in check constraint by design:

> **•Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following
>   constructs:**
>
> •Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions
>
> •Calls to the functions that are not deterministic (CURRENT_DATE,
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE, LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE,
>   SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and USERENV)
>
> **•Calls to user-defined functions**
>
> •Dereferencing of REF columns (for example, using the DEREF function)
>
> •Nested table columns or attributes
>
> •The pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, or ROWNUM
>
> •Date constants that are not fully specified

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm

Comment: To get rid of this limitation a virtual column should help.

Comment: @Wernfried it must be a deterministic function/expression, which is not the case here

Comment: Well, Oracle accepts function like this `CREATE FUNCTION DETERMINISTIC_CHEAT RETURN INTEGER DETERMINISTIC IS BEGIN RETURN DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM; END;` without any error. Of course, it will not work from logical point of view.

Answer (score -3):

Try running every statement in that function, This is the case of non existent column for a table or using a not existing row.