# Oracle SQL add check constraint at multiple table level

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-tables, check-constraint

I have two tables as below.

create table emp (empno varchar2(5), position varchar2(5));

create table info (empno varchar2(5), nick varchar2(20));

empno is the primary key for both tables and empno is also a foreign key in info, with parent table emp.

**Now I want to add a check constraint so that except for the gm or catcher( value in column position), the nick should not exceed 16 letters.**

I tried the UDF method as below.

```
create function checkPos (@empno varchar2(5))
returns bit
as
begin
declare @par bit

select @par = CASE WHEN pos = 'gm' or pos = 'catcher'
THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM emp
WHERE empno = @empno

RETURN(@par)
END

ALTER TABLE info ADD CONSTRAINT info_nick_ck CHECK (checkPos(empno) * length(nick) <16);
```

However, it does not work in oracle live sql.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You said that you are using Oracle, but your code looks more like TSQL code to me

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like TSQL code.

Try this function in Oracle:

```
create function checkPos (p_empno varchar2)
return number
as
    v_par number := 0;
begin
    select case 
            when pos = 'gm'
                or pos = 'catcher'
                then 0
            else 1
            end into v_par
    from emp
    where empno = p_empno;

    return v_par;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('No data found');
        -- Do something about it
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi GurV, thanks for your reply. I am a new-hand and I wrote the UDF after reading some previous questions and answers. Did not know that was TSQL. Sorry. I tried your advise, but oracle live sql kept telling me "Errors: FUNCTION CHECKPOS
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" ". Any ideas?

Comment: I tested it on livesql. Did you add the forward slash at the end of the function?

Comment: My fault. Thank you! After I add the forward slash, the function worked. However, the check constraint statement "ALTER TABLE info ADD CONSTRAINT info_nick_ck CHECK (checkPos(empno) * length(nick) <16);" gives an error saying "ORA-00904: "CHECKPOS": invalid identifier ".  Why? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Regarding that visiting this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778948/check-constraint-calling-a-function-oracle-sql-developer