# sqldeveloper check in foreign key table attribute

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables:

- BIRACI(ID, broj_biraca)
- PRAVNI_AKT_PREDLOG_BIRACA(Pravni_akt_id, ID_biraca(FK from BIRACI)

When I want to insert into table `PRAVNI_AKT_PREDLOG_BIRACA` I need some rule to check if inserted `ID_biraca` has its attribute in table BIRACI with the condition `broj_biraca > 15000`.

I need something to show error like "Insertion not possible, BIRACI with that ID isnt having 15000 or more in broj_biraca"...
Is this possible?

Comment: A constraint won't help you here, but a pre-insert trigger could perform the validation.

Comment: Please tag you DBMS. SQL Developer is an IDE that can connect to different DBMS

Comment: It may be possible with ref constraint to the calculated column `case when broj_biraca > 15000 then id end`

Comment: how to tag my dbms

Comment: how do i do that @astentx "It may be possible with ref constraint to the calculated column case when broj_biraca > 15000 then id end"

Comment: I presume you connect to the Oracle database, but... Try `select * from v$version` or `select version()` to obtain the information about your DBMS and add it's tag instead of sql-developer tag by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72035360/edit)

Comment: but my dbms is oraclesqldeveloper

Comment: [Oracle SQL Developer is a free **graphical tool** that enhances productivity and simplifies database development tasks.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer/index.html) It doesn't manage databases in the way DBMS do, it just allows you to access the database run by some DBMS

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle expert but I've searched a bit and it seems that Oracle doesn't support check constraints that reference another table.

2 potential workarounds:

1. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880853/6996150 it could work via a user defined function (however this seems not the case according to Oracle's documentation; cf. the following approach).
2. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41467321/6996150 it could be done via virtual columns.

Hopefully you can make it work!